# UPDATE and READKEY at the same time?

Tags: progress-4gl

In my application I'm building, I'd like for the first screen to be an UPDATE to an integer, but I'd like to have an option to press F2 to access a different kind of functionality in the program.

When I try it the logical way, I get buzzed at since the UPDATE is expecting INTEGER only input, and I'm pressing F2.

Can you UPDATE and READKEY successfully at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do it the old way with editing blocks - try reading up on event-driven programming, where the code describes events and what gets run when a certain event happens. The code would look something like this:

```
ON F2 of update-field
   DO: /* something */
   END.

UPDATE update-field.
```

Better yet, don't use "UPDATE", do a "WAIT-FOR" instead.

Comment: Thanks man, I was trying to do something similar, but couldn't get the perfect storm of code placement/keyword usage.  I got it working.  Thanks again!